# ML Pipeline OneHotEncoder is not fit

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, error-handling, data-science

I'm new to data science and I am able to build a model and put a pipeline along with onehotencoder. However, when I call the function that I build, it gives an error. Please see below and please advice. Thanks in advance!

```
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('ohe', OneHotEncoder()),
                  ('rfc', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,criterion="entropy",max_features=None))])  
pickle.dump(clf,open('model.pkl','wb'))

# load model
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

def predict(A,B,C,D,E,F,G):

    result = model.predict(x)

    # send back to browser
    output = {'results': int(result[0])}


    # return data
    return jsonify(results=output)
```

to call function:

```
predict('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')
```

Error:

```
NotFittedError: This OneHotEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to transform your data before feeding it the RandomForestClassifier:

```
def trainPipeline(pipeline, X, y):
    X_transformed = X
    for name, step in pipeline.steps[:-1]:
        X_transformed = step.fit_transform(X_transformed, y)
    pipeline.steps[-1][1].fit(X_transformed, y)
```

Note: This will only work if your pipeline has two steps and first one is the OneHotEncoder().

Comment: There's right, I've added the OneHotEncoder() in a pipeline before pickle to a file. Can you please review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238345/pipeline-with-onehotencoder-random-forest-classifier?noredirect=1#comment467417_238345

Comment: In the review link code when you create the pipeline you are passing in the OneHotEncoder() as a new instance of it, instead of doing that pass in the onehotencoder variable that you already fitted.

Comment: That's what I thought too! How should I tweak my code to ensure that the model is trained in after OneHotEncoder, but def predict call function is before OHE? Can you please advice?  @Piyush Sharma

Comment: You can check the step execution order by using clf.steps() when you call clf.fit() the output from the first step is passed on to the second step.

Comment: You are directly using clf.fit() but this would not work as the first step has the OneHotEncoder and the data needs to be transformed before fitting it check the other answer I have updated it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It make sens. May I asked where do you update the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209038/discussion-between-cassie-l-and-piyush-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

- Using the scikit-learn library, you need to fit an estimator before using it to make predictions.
- You are passing a variable `x` which is not defined in your code.
- You never use any of the arguments passed to `predict`.
- If you are trying to load a pre-trained model, you should not overwrite it by the unfitted Pipeline object that you instantiate.

**Long version**

Depending on what you mean by "building a model" it is questionable whether you have actually done that here.

In Data Science, the first thing you should do is understand what problem you are trying to solve. After that, you need to collect a dataset, analyze it and decide whether it can reasonably answer your problem. Finally, you can build a model and use your dataset to train that model (i.e. tune the parameters of the model) and only after that will you be able to make any kind of predictions.

I would recommend that you dig into and try to understand some of the underlying theory of Machine Learning, and what it actually means to build a model, before attempting to do it in practice.